# Visual Studio 2015 - Turn off "'private' modifier is redundant" IntelliSense warning (RECS014)

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Is it possible to turn off the "'private' modifier is redundant" (RECS014) IntelliSense warning?

Comment: Turns out that this warning comes from the Refactoring Essentials extension.  I have marked the answer that explain how to ignore this rule as the answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. Install the [Refactoring Essentials](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/68c1575b-e0bf-420d-a94b-1b0f4bcdcbcc) extension.
2. Inside VS, expand the 'References' node in Solution Explorer and right click on 'Analyzers' and select 'Open Active Rule Set'
3. Expand the 'RefactoringEssentials' node and change `RECS0145` from `Warning` to `None`
4. Repeat for all other projects or copy and paste the `.ruleset` file into other projects and manually change the name and description (the file is simply XML)

---

https://github.com/icsharpcode/RefactoringEssentials/wiki/Custom-Rule-Sets-for-Analyzers

Comment: The SO link the warning links to says it is better to use the private modifier...

Answer (score 1):

No google solution found, so I tried for a while finding the solution.

If you want to suppress only a specific private entry, use something like:

```
#pragma warning disable RECS0145
    private int myvar;
#pragma warning restore RECS0145
```

If you want to suppress all these warnings into a whole file, use the #pragma at the beginning of the file:

`#pragma warning disable RECS0145`

If you want to disable the warning in the whole project, use a compiler directive: open the project's properties, go in the "Build" tab and add the comma-separated list of codes you wish to suppress in the "Suppress warning" textbox.

[image]

Comment: Whoa, Comic Sans in Visual Studio!

Answer (score 1):

[Refactoring Essentials Plugin](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/68c1575b-e0bf-420d-a94b-1b0f4bcdcbcc), proposes multiple fixes for this warning.

1. Using `#pragma` directive as Gianpiero has mentioned
2. In addition there is a project level fix : place following line in *GlobalSuppressions.cs* project file:
   `[assembly: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Redundancies in Code", "RECS0145:Removes 'private' modifiers that are not required")]`